# MongoDB query to search text within nested array without field names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with hundreds of documents containing our AWS EC2 instance info. I need a query to search for documents containing particular IP address (eg: 1.2.3.7). The IP info is in an array without field names.

Example documents:

```
{"generated": "01-Dec-2019","data":[
["default","Jenkins1","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.4","10.1.2.3"],
["default","Jenkins2","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.5","10.1.2.4"]
]}

{"generated": "02-Dec-2019","data":[
["default","Jenkins1","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.4","10.1.2.3"],
["default","Jenkins3","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.6","10.1.2.5"]
]}

{"generated": "03-Dec-2019","data":[
["default","Jenkins1","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.4","10.1.2.3"],
["default","Jenkins4","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.7","10.1.2.6"]
]}

{"generated": "04-Dec-2019","data":[
["default","Jenkins6","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.9","10.1.2.8"],
["default","Jenkins5","running","us-east-1a","1.2.3.8","10.1.2.7"]
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to check if an array, which is an element of another array, contains the IP you are looking for:

```
db.collection.find({
  data: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $in: ["1.2.3.7"]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You can run this query in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R8IxAqp6BDI).